# Django OSError [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/django/media_cdn/1.png' solution

Tags: python, django

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
#'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, height_field="height_field", width_field ="width_field")
```

The error text is written in the title. It is telling me it doesn't have permission.Please help...

Comment: What is the output of "ls -ld /home/django/media_cdn/"? Also, can you confirm the user your app is running as?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to this... Where would I look for the output? I think the user I left it as "root".

Comment: If you could run "ls -ld /home/django/media_cdn/" in a shell window it will show the permissions for the folder. Then we can understand whether the permissions need to be modified.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 28 18:28 /home/django/media_cdn/

Comment: Thanks. So the folder is owned by root, and I would therefore guess that the application is running as a user different to root. How do you start the application? Do you know what user the application is running as?

Comment: No actually I start the app with root. like... ssh root@(ip adress) and then I enter a passward.

Comment: Try allowing write permissions on that folder with `chmod 757 /home/django/media_cdn/` and then repeat the original operation. See if that resolves.

Comment: Hmm... now the error is fixed but the image is still not showing on the website...

Comment: the output is now

Comment: drwxr-xrwx 2 root root 4096